# Android repeating async Task never calls onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, locking

I have an async Task that repeats itself, until a statement is true. Therefore I use this code(simplified):

```
public class AnalyzingTask extends AsyncTask<String, JSONObject, Void>
{
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private final Condition tryAgain = lock.newCondition();
private volatile boolean finished = false;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
{
    try
    {
        lock.lockInterruptibly();

        do {

    ...somecode...
    publishProgress(result)

            tryAgain.await();
        }
        while (!finished);

        lock.unlock();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        publishProgress(null);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(JSONObject... result)
{
    ..someCode...

    if(state.equals("Available"))
                {

                    terminateTask();

                }
                else
                {
                    runAgain();
                }

}

public void runAgain() {
    // Call this to request data from the server again
    tryAgain.signal();
}

public void terminateTask() {
    // The task will only finish when we call this method
    finished = true;
    if(lock.isLocked())
    {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    // Make sure we clean up if the task is killed
    terminateTask();
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
{
   return;
}
```

}

I debugged this code, and terminateTask() gets called normal, after "state" has the right value.
Nevertheless, onPostExecuted never gets called. It wouldn't be a problem, but I cant start another Task, as long as this one is running.

Why is this Task not finishing as normal?

Stacktrace when adding signal() as asked in the comments:

```
8008-8008/com.michi.undroid E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.michi.undroid, PID: 8008
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.signal(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1917)
        at com.michi.undroid.AnalyzingTask.terminateTask(AnalyzingTask.java:166)
        at com.michi.undroid.AnalyzingTask$1.run(AnalyzingTask.java:127)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: are you sure the `doInBackground` hits the return statement ?

Comment: you are right... it never gets called but why?

Comment: I guess because it is still locked on the condition, can you add the signal() also for terminateTask?

Comment: Is it possible finished is always set to true so your loop continues infinitely?

Comment: The apps stopps when I add it :(

Comment: @zgc7009 no, i stepped through, its not a infinite loop.

Comment: @user3800301 do you mind adding the stacktrace of the crash?

Comment: @user3800301 as long as `finished` is false, it is an infinite loop

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.avcomparatives.michi.undroid, PID: 8008
    java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException hope this helps

Comment: no it does not. Copy the whole stacktrace, edit your question and paste into

Comment: added it to my question :)

Comment: I think that I am getting to the point. Do you know How condition and reentrantlock work? I am not familiar with those two construct but looks like the lock have to be acquired and release within the same thread

Comment: No I am not familiar with it...do you know a solution?

Comment: it would be easier if you try to explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I want to have an async Task, that repeats itself as long as state != Availabl